# Completely remove SVG icon load in child theme of Twenty Twenty-one theme

Tags: svg, theme-twenty-twenty-one

How to Completely remove SVG icon load in child theme of the Twenty Twenty-one theme?

Comment: Why do you want to, what are you trying to achieve? SVG is very well supported nowadays.

Comment: see [this answer](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/removing-svg-icon-load/)

Comment: I don't use icons at my site. It's unnecessary load.

Comment: About the answer you referenced to: (1) it's about svg fro JetPack (20 IN Twenty twenty theme. So totally irrelevant! Thank you for your time.